# Powershell doesn't seem to accept target paths with spaces in Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying do it calling a executable in powershell to do decompression in all `.fla` files, it seems works only in path without space.

Can someone help?

This is what I am doing, and it is working only in non space folders:

```
Powershell "Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *fla |ForEach-Object {.\fla2comp.exe -d $_.FullName}"
```

Comment: As currently shown, your command shouldn't have a problem with paths with spaces. Are you showing us the actual command line you're using? Please also post the full error message you're getting.

Comment: Where in the folder name is the space?  If in the middle, I see no reason for you to have a problem.  But if the space is at the end of the folder, yeah, I had that problem about 2 weeks ago.  Couldn't access the folder without prefixing '\\?\" to the folder path.  In your example, probably `.\fla2comp.exe -d "\\?\$($_.FullName)"`, but I have hard time believing you just randomly have the exact same problem I had.  The odds are against that.

Comment: Hi guys, I figure out, is not the command is the program files folder (the folder i am tryiing to use the command, i dont know why, but it not get permission to save files on it.
Have some possibility to launch the command with adm previligies?
try it Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs "Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *fla |ForEach-Object {.\fla2comp.exe -d $_.FullName}"

but gives me denied acess.
its funny because i am adm of the computer.

Comment: Try with one hardcoded file first. If that works, you may find that changing the filter to `'*.fla'` helps, because now your code may try to send other files to the fla2comp.exe simply because they have a name ending with 'fla'.